# Get same string value from reg subfolders

Tags: powershell

I am trying to export from registry multiple string records with name 'PackageName' from `Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Patches\` Under it there is subfolders with arbitrary name similar to `'1636371008E66D24FB90522C7ECB2F2F'` and at the end `\SourceList`

So full patch to each folder is

> HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Patches\1636371008E66D24FB90522C7ECB2F2F\SourceList

Each string contains Data starting with `'OASyS DNA *'`

Problems started since each machine have different number of installed patches and different arbitrary names for installation package `'1636371008E66D24FB90522C7ECB2F2F'`.

Was working with `Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Patches\`

&

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Patches\1636371008E66D24FB90522C7ECB2F2F\SourceList PackageName
```

I could get single value, but not full list of installed hotfixes.

> OASyS DNA Infrastructure-Arbitration Hotfix 8.0.2.2.msp

Comment: `Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Patches\*\SourceList | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object PackageName -like 'OASyS DNA *'`

Comment: Thanks. I have just expand it to cover all information .

Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\ | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object ProductName -Like 'OASyS DNA *' | foreach {$_.ProductName}| Sort-Object
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Dependencies\ | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object DisplayName -Like 'OASyS *' | Where-Object Version | foreach {$_.DisplayName; $_.Version} | Sort-Object
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Patches\*\SourceList | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object PackageName -like 'OASyS DNA *' | foreach {$_.PackageName} | Sort-Object